# How to send id from controller to js in Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I need to generate a big report file in background. Here is a simple view to create a `OrderReport` object.

```
<%= simple_form_for order_report, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :start_date, as: :date, html5: true %>
  <%= f.input :end_date, as: :date, html5: true %>
  <%= f.submit "Generate report", id: "test" %>
<% end %>
```

And that what is going on in the controller:

```
def create
   order_report = OrderReport.new(order_report_params)
   order_report.user = current_user
   order_report.save

   OrderReportJob.new(order_report).delay.perform

   render nothing: true
end
```

After user click a submit button this action creates a background process to generate report. I wrote endpoint to check the status of this background job. This JS is a `onclick` function to Submit buttom by id #test

```
$.ajax({
      url: report_url,
      success: function(report) {
        if(report.status === 'progress') {
          $("#spin").show();
          $interval = setInterval(checkStatus, 3000);
        }
      }
    });
```

This is a part of the JS script. It works good, but the final step to send the ID of created `OrderReport` to this js file. As you can see in the JS script I have a variable `report_url` - it's already hardcoded and looks like

```
var report_url = '/order_reports/1'
```

So the main idea is to catch the ID of created `OrderReport`, if it's possible, and use it in the JS script. How can I pass it correctly?

Update:

order_report.js

```
$(function () {
  $('#test').click(function() {
    var report_url = '/order_reports/39'

    $.ajax({
      url: report_url,
      success: function(report) {
        if(report.status === 'progress') {
          $interval = setInterval(checkStatus, 3000);
        }
      }
    });

    function checkStatus() {
      $.ajax({
        url: report_url,
        success: function(report) {
          if(report.status === 'done') {
            clearInterval($interval)
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you try `render json` and pass the ID of the report at that moment?

Answer (score 1):

A more RESTful solution is to use meaningful response codes to tell the client what happened with the request:

```
def create
   order_report = OrderReport.new(order_report_params)
   order_report.user = current_user

   respond_to do |format|
     if order_report.save
       OrderReportJob.new(order_report).delay.perform
       format.json { head :created, location: order_report }
     else
       format.json { head :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
end
```

`head :created, location: order_report` returns a `201 - Created` response with a `location` header that contains a url to the created resource.

This lets you listen for the Rails UJS [`ajax:success` and `ajax:error` events](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax):

```
<%= simple_form_for order_report, remote: true, html: { class: 'order_report_form', 'data-type' => 'json'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :start_date, as: :date, html5: true %>
  <%= f.input :end_date, as: :date, html5: true %>
  <%= f.submit "Generate report", id: "test" %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', '.order_report_form', function(e, data, status, xhr){
  function checkStatus(url) {
    return $.getJSON(url).then(function(data) {
      // some logic here to test if we have desired result
      if (!desiredResult) {
        // never use setInterval with ajax as it does not care
        // if the previous request is done.
        // instead use setTimeout with recursion
        setTimeout(1000, function(){ checkStatus(url) });
      } else {
        // do something awesome
      }
    }
  }
  checkStatus(xhr.getResponseHeader('location'));
});

$(document).on('ajax:error', '.order_report_form', function(){
  alert("Oops");
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer, header with location works. But I still can't catch the location in js. I updated the answer with whole js file to check the status with 3 seconds delay. Can u update ur answer please according to my js?